# Bash script throws too many arguments error

Tags: bash, less

I have this bash script that looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in src/styles/*.less src/styles/brand/*.less
do
  filename=$(basename "$f")
  if [ ${filename:0:1} != '_' ]; then
    lessc --no-color -x "${f}" "$(sed 's|^src/styles/|httpdocs/css/|;s/.less$/.css/' <<< $f)"
  fi
done
```

It is supposed to compile a series of .less files in the style and brand directories, I think. When I run it though, I get this:

`./compile_less.sh: line 6: [: too many arguments`

Any idea what is going wrong here? I'm a newb with bash scripts and am using this one from a former co-worker.

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, using `[[ ]]` rather than `[ ]` would avoid this problem entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an existing answer that addresses best practices, but doesn't explain why it's a too-many-arguments error.

`"${filename:0:1}"` needs double quotes if you want to ensure that it will always be one word, and not zero words or several words -- if it comes out empty, it's zero words, so you run `[ != _ ]`.

Leaving out the quotes is even worse if the first character is a `*` -- then it expands to one word per file in the current directory, and that's *far* too many operands.

`[ != _ ]` is too many arguments because there's nothing in a position to be a binary operator, so `[` expects to see only a single operand.

`[ all your filenames here != _ ]` is too many arguments for a far less subtle reason. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using

```
for f in src/styles/*.less src/styles/brand/*.less
```

is that if no file matches the then `f` will be `src/styles/*.less src/styles/brand/*.less` and `filename` will be `*.less`. This causes problem in the `if` statement.

You can check if file exists and continue:

```
  ...
  [[ ! -e "${f}" ]] && continue # or any other appropriate action 
  filename=$(basename "$f")
  ...
```

Comment: Did you mean `[[ ! -e "${f}" ]] ` ??

Comment: `filename` is supposed to be the basename.

Comment: Another option is to put `shopt -s nullglob` at the top of the script, such that globs that don't match don't expand to anything at all.

Comment: The reason it causes problems in the `if` statement is that the first character is `*` and the shell expands it. Sometimes you can catch weird things like this if you run `set -x` at the start of your script, or by invoking the shell as `bash -x`.